# How to detect redraw rate (fps) of a css animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, frame-rate

I'm interested in the fluency of my CSS animations. As some extra points:

- I'm mostly interested in performance on mobile devices (WebKit),
- It would help if data could be gathered during normal operation (with real users doing real things).

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113245/instrument-webkit-to-provide-fps-information-for-css-animations

Comment: Chrome desktop has a `FPS counter` flag in `about:flags`. Try putting `about:flags` or `about:labs` in the url of the adroid browser; might work there too.

Comment: @Gerben Thanks, I tried them, but none of them work on the mobile browser. I will try out a setTimeout version based on `window.computedStyle`. Let's hope the question is not closed by then... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Beta for Android supports getting FPS by setting flag in chrome://flags

Answer (score 1):

Negative answer: `window.getComputedStyle` will not yield any result because the JS program itself (so the number of mesurements) will slow down on high animation load.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/9xQ5H/17/